# Gender showing for table and Font Color based on age for Table

Tags: html, css, angular

I need my table to list out the genders of the heroes as `"M"` or `"F"` in the table based on the gender of the heroes whether its male or female. So if its Male it will only show out as "M". Furthermore, I need the fonts to be of specific color based on the ages. For example, if `0 < age <= 20`  font `color #000000(black)`. if `20 < age <= 50 = font color #85929E`

I don't know how to Bind the `hero.gender` data to the table to show M or F & and bind the font colors to the age.

```
  <table>

      <tr>
        <th>Hero ID</th>
        <th>Hero Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Superpower</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>

      <!-- <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
              <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}"> -->
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(hero.superpowers)}">
              <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.name}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.gender}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.age}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.superpowers}}</span></td>
  </a>
    <td><button class="delete" title="delete hero"
        (click)="delete(hero)">X</button></td>

      </tr>

  </table>
```

Mock-heroes:

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr.Incredible', gender: 'Male', superpowers: 'Super Strength', age: 10  },
  { id: 12, name: 'Missappear', gender: 'Female', superpowers: 'Invisibility', age: 29  },
  { id: 13, name: 'Jetstream', gender: 'Female', superpowers: 'Flying', age: 32 },
  { id: 14, name: 'Nightcrawler', gender: 'Male', superpowers: 'Shapeshifting', age: 17 },
  { id: 15, name: 'Flash', gender: 'Female', superpowers: 'Super Speed', age: 23 },
  { id: 16, name: 'Professor X', gender: 'Male', superpowers: 'Telepathy', age: 38 },
  { id: 17, name: 'Jean Grey', gender: 'Female', superpowers: 'Telekinesis', age: 35 },
  { id: 18, name: 'Wolverine', gender: 'Male', superpowers: 'Regeneration', age: 24 },
];
```

Comment: I have added solution on stackblitz please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-oowk9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change color based on **condition** you need to use `ngStyle` directive like below

**component.html**

```
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(hero.superpowers)}">

        <td><span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.name}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.gender == 'Male' ? 'M': 'F'}}</span></td>
    <td [ngStyle]="{ 'color' : getColorByAge(hero.age) }"> <span class="badge"  >{{hero.age}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.superpowers}}</span></td>
    <td><button class="delete" title="delete hero">X</button></td>

  </tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
  getColorByAge(age) {

    switch (true) {
      case age > 0 && age <= 20:
        return '#000000';
      case age > 20 && age <= 50:
        return '#85929E';
    }
  }
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-oowk9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `<td>` in the table with something like the following:

```
<td><span class="badge" *ngIf="hero.gender === 'Male'">
<span [ngClass]="{'black-text' : hero.age <= 20}">M</span>
<span [ngClass]="{'other-text' :  hero.age > 20 && hero.age <= 50}">M</span>
</span></td>
```

Just created the css classes, and then do what you need to with the Female variant.

Above is just an example I wrote on here and might not actually compile successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**Use to change color**

`[style.color]="hero.age <= 20 ? '#000000': hero.age <= 50 ? '#85929E' : 'green'"`

**Use**  **to see only `M/F`**:

`{{hero.gender.charAt(0)}}`

***Here is the code***

```
  <td><span class="badge" [style.color]="hero.age <= 20 ? '#000000': hero.age <= 50 ? '#85929E' : 'green'">{{hero.gender.charAt(0)}}</span></td>
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-a4hopm?file=src/app/app.component.html)